# number of distinct simple graphs with n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

To calculate simple, labelled graphs is easy with the formula $2^{n(n-1)/2}$, but if we say distinct, then it would certainly be less than it, because some possible situations will be same hence not distinct, how to calculate number of "distinct" graphs?

Comment: See [A000088 - OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000088) and [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Graphs_on_three_and_four_vertices).

Comment: @d125q so Isomorphic graphs are put into one category, Polya theorem talks only about 3 and 4 vertices, is it appliable on higher number of vertices?

Comment: Yes, it is. For large $n$, the number of isomorphism classes of graphs of $n$ vertices is asymptotic to $2^n / n!$, but I am not sure if there is an exact formula. In any case, the OEIS entry should provide a lot of information.

Comment: @d125q good lord :) math is fun :) thanks.

Comment: @d125q: the correct asymptotic expression is $2^{\binom{n}{2}}/n!$.